# ListView will not display elements from Array : Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to implement a `ListView` in an Android Application **using Android Studio.** I have followed three different tutorials, and done exactly as they instructed to no avail. The view loads, but the list does not display any elements.

**SelectionActivity.java**

```
package thosekids.com.finder_sohacks4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView userList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);


    String[] users = {"U 1", "U 2", "U 3"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
    userList.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

**activity_selection.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="thosekids.com.finder_sohacks4.SelectionActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchingText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Who are you looking for?"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/userList"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="427dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Below Listview"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You need to use one xml with simple one textview check this link you will definitely get what you want https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: If the view is loading as you mentioned, then can you check if the text in the list items is coming up white or transparent? Just click on the items and see if some text is visible.

Comment: I just replace Constraintlayout with relative layout and its run perfect and data are also shown..

Comment: Do accept the answers which helped you to reach your solution.

Comment: Thanks Kevach. Just did. The problem ended up being with the code that started this activity, not in the lines above but these posts were still helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow My code and try to implement your code.

```
   package com.example.ListDisplay;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListDisplay extends Activity {
   // Array of strings...
   String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
      "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

**References:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

https://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

activity_selection.xml file in **"android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"** replace with **"RelativeLayout"** and show all element in list view.